# New Task in PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following code in my Page_Load method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t = new Task(() => { listener.Recv(); });
    t.Start();

}
```

I know every HTTP request starts a new thread and I think for every HTTP request a new Task will be created/started. 
My question is what will happen to previous task which is already running. Will the task automatically shutdown?
Is there a way in which I make sure that previous task is closed before starting new one?

Comment: Doing async stuff in asp.net is usually a bad idea, because you can't control the important stuff. If we want async processing, we usually use ajax and call methods that way, so that is doesn't block other parts of the website from rendering. Why do you even want to use Tasks like this in page load? Doesn't make much sense. And no, task won't be automatically shutdown...

Comment: Simplify: Task.Run(() => listener.Recv());

Comment: @Cyberdrew, how is that related to the question?